# Meaning of HA-Proxy log

Tags: haproxy, haproxy-ingress

Getting following log in HA-Proxy, and its not hitting to my spring-boot application's controller method. And also it is not mentioning the http status code as well. but other requests has http status code.

```
Nov 4 11:56:31 localhost haproxy[24972]: 112.134.131.29:17817 [04/Nov/2021:11:56:31.862] myservice k8-sit-masters/k8-master-2 0/0/0/-1/0 -1 0 - - SD--           2/2/0/0/0 0/0 "POST /path/to/my/url HTTP/1.1"
```

Any idea what the meaning of this log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Nov 4 11:56:31             => Log Time Stamp
localhost                  => Hostname or IP address of HAProxy host
haproxy[24972]             => Process ID for the HAProxy process
112.134.131.29:17817       => Source IP:Source Port
[04/Nov/2021:11:56:31.862] => Request Accepted timestamp
myservice                  => Front-end name
k8-sit-masters/k8-master   => Target request was routed to
0/0/0/-1/0                 => Time waiting for full request from client (ms) / Time waiting in queues (ms) / Time to establish connection to destination server (ms) / Time for destination server to send response (ms) / Total time request active in HAProxy (ms)
-1                         => http status
 0                         => bytes read
 - -                       => Pptional values (captured request cookie, captured response cookie)
 SD--                      => Termination state, cookie status
 2/2/0/0/0                 => Active connections / Front-end connections / Back-end connections / Server connections / Retries
 0/0                       => Server queue size / Back-end queue size
 "POST /path/to/my/url HTTP/1.1" => Request method, API URL, http version
```

Reference: [HAProxy Log definition](https://www.haproxy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/aloha_load_balancer_memo_log.pdf)

As we can see in the log http status code is -1. -1 indicates that the status code is not available. The reason is in the termination flags field. In your case [termination flag](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#8.5) value is SD. Here

```
S => the TCP session was unexpectedly aborted by the server, or the
        server explicitly refused it.
D => the session was killed by haproxy because the server was detected
        as down and was configured to kill all connections when going down.
```

Comment: The interpretation of termination flags here is wrong. The letter place is important!
"SD--" S is in the first place (server disconnected), D in the second place (Data phase). The link to documentation you provided holds more explanation